# ERROR: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: networking, apt

What happens is that apt-get randomly fails to fetch packages.

First of all, I have seen some other answers to this question going to:

- temporary issue
- not temporary issue, fix some settings about DNS

In my case, I have a dynamic environment with dynamic mirror selection.
So on large scale it's indeed a temporary issue and some percentage of dynamically created VMs fail this way.

What I am looking for is a setup for apt to tell it not to give up and keep trying mirrors until it works instead of fast fail, at least certain amount of times.